# Imagemagick Rotate only one item

Tags: command-line, rotation, imagemagick

I have the following command. I am trying to get just the text to rotate 90º however the item immediately after it also rotates. I tried using () brackets with no luck. I only want the text rotated. Any ideas?

```
exec("convert {$background} {$flare} -composite \( -rotate 90 -gravity southwest -pointsize 80 -draw \"text 10,10 'TOKEN ID'\" \) {$head} -composite {$body} -composite {$screen} -composite ../media_assets/outline_overlay.png -composite {$over_screen} {$output}");
```

Comment: You're not giving us much of a clue here. What language is it please? Does it use a shell? Which shell? What OS is it? Can you run the command just in Terminal, instead of via `exec`? Can you simplify the command to use less irrelevant stuff? Thank you.